# Catching "$Canceled" from SystemDialogInput

Tags: files-and-directories, dialog-window

Below is a minimal example of a DynamicModule which has a button to call up a SystemDiaglogInput to allow the user to select a directory.  If the user selects a directory, then the name of that directory is displayed.  If the user selects "Cancel" then "try again" should be displayed.

Am unable to catch the "$Canceled" case.  Certainly a rookie mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

```
importMod = DynamicModule[{dataDirName, initDirectory = "C:", 
    , output = "Click the Choose directory button"
    }, Panel[Column[
     {
      Button["Choose  directory ...",
       output = "Selecting directory ...";
       dataDirName = SystemDialogInput["Directory", initDirectory];
       If[SameQ[ dataDirName, "$Canceled"]
        ,  output = "try again";
        , output = Last@FileNameSplit[dataDirName];
        ];
       output;, Method -> "Queued"]
      , Panel[
       Pane[Dynamic[ output, TrackedSymbols :> {output}], {200, 120}]]
      }
     ]
    ]
   ];
importMod
```

Comment: You're right; It's a very simple error. You should write `If[SameQ[dataDirName, $Canceled], ...]`, not `If[SameQ[dataDirName, "$Canceled"], ...]`. `$Canceled` is returned as a symbol not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment to your question, it's a simple error, but I'm  giving you a full rewrite of your code to show you how it can be simplified.

```
DynamicModule[
    {dataDirName,
     initDirectory = $HomeDirectory,
     output = "Click the Choose directory button"},
  Panel[
    Column[
      {Button[
         "Choose directory ...",
         output = "Selecting directory ...";
         dataDirName = SystemDialogInput["Directory", initDirectory];
         output =
           If[dataDirName === $Canceled, 
             "try again", 
             Last @ FileNameSplit[dataDirName]],
         Method -> "Queued"],
       Panel[Pane[Dynamic[output], {200, 50}], Background -> White]}]]]
```

[image: panel]

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate your help with this.